# associate the country with each tennis player on match rows using pandas merge

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have tennis matches results in one dataset:

```
df_games

match_date  tournament  player1_name    player1_result  player2_name    player2_result
09-20-2020  tourn_1     john            2               dussin          0
09-20-2020  tourn_1     manole          0               clezar          2
09-20-2020  tourn_2     boyer           2               louis           1
```

I have another dataset with probability of winning for each player:

```
df_countries

plyer   player_country
manole  USA
boyer   CA
john    IND
clezar  FRA
dussin  USA
louis   ITA
```

I want to add the country of each player to the matches table, so the result would be like that:

```
match_date  tournament  player1_name    player1_country player1_result  player2_name    player2_country player2_result
09-20-2020  tourn_1     john            IND             2               dussin          USA             0
09-20-2020  tourn_1     manole          USA             0               clezar          FRA             2
09-20-2020  tourn_2     boyer           CA              2               louis           ITA             1
```

I tried this but didn't work:

```
new_df = pd.merge(df_games, df_countries,  how='left', left_on=['player1_name','player'], right_on = ['player2_name','player'])
```

Comment: `new_df = pd.merge(df_games, df_countries,  how='left', left_on='player1_name', right_on = 'player')`

Comment: what about player2 ?

Comment: `left_on='[player1_name,player]', right_on = '[player2_name,player]'`...The quotes should be for the column names`left_on=['player1_name','player'], right_on = ['player2_name','player']`

Comment: merge again with `left_on='player2_name'`?

Comment: @Quang Hoang if merge again, will erase the first merge results (become NaN)

Answer (score 0):

Let's do with map:

```
to_map = df_countries.drop_duplicates('player').set_index('player')['player_country']

df_games['player1_country'] = df['player1_name'].map(to_map)
df_games['player2_country'] = df['player2_name'].map(to_map)
```

Comment: return an error: ```InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects```

Comment: @khaledkoubaa that means you have duplicated player names with possibly different countries. You need to decide what to do with those, one option is drop the duplicated names as updated in the answer.

Comment: I removed duplicates, but the result is not accurate, the 2 new columns values don't match